# rawQuery not updating database with cursor.moveToFirst, android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm having some difficulty getting my database updated. Basically the user will input data into two separate places, so we get

```
Name    | Letter  | Marks   
----------------------------
Dave    | Null    | 90
Dave    | A       | Null
```

which should become

```
Dave    | A       | 90
```

However, nothing is updating. The query works perfectly when I try it in SQLite Manager, so I must be implementing cursor wrong.

```
    public void insertData(String name, int mark_column, String marks) {
        String [] columns = new String[] {COL_3, COL_4, COL_5};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(columns[mark_column], marks);
        db.replace(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        //The code above works as desired
        String sql = "SELECT NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(LETTER, ', ') AS LETTER," +
            "GROUP_CONCAT(MARKS, ', ') AS MARKS FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " GROUP BY NAME";
        //This query works in SQLite Manager
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }
```

I have tried various combinations of c.moveToLast, not having c.moveToNext, etc. This method is called in onClick of an Alert Dialog.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: try to Use execSQL() instead of rawquery()

Comment: I don't understand. Is the database update not working, or is the database query not working? Or do you have some UI that isn't updating?

Comment: Sorry, the database update is not working but the database query works in SQLite Manager, so I think I'm not using c.moveToFirst() correctly.

Comment: `Cursor`s are used for queries, not for updates. Whatever issue you are having with `Cursor`s is a separate problem.

Comment: What is the schema for this table? And can you also show the values for some of the constants (`COL_3`, `COL_4`, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding the cursor:**

I don't see anything wrong with your query. If you aren't "seeing" any results in your app, it's likely because you aren't actually doing anything with the results. They exist in memory in a `Cursor` object, but that's all; if you want to see anything you have to bind that data to some UI components, or dump it to logcat, or something.

Note that if you were to add code inside of your `while` loop, you would skip the first row of the cursor because you would have a `moveToFirst()` call followed immediately by a `moveToNext()` call. This is how I iterate over a `Cursor`, and it always works:

```
if (cusor != null) {
    try {
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // do something with data in current row
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

**Regarding the update:**

You actually aren't doing an update *per se*, you are doing an insert. `SQLiteDatabase.replace()` executes this command:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tableName(columns) VALUES (values);
```

This can work as an update only if you have a constraint on the table and the insertion of a new row with these values would violate that constraint (the exact handling for different constraint violations is described [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)). For the constraint types that I suspect you are expecting, this operation will delete the existing row and insert a new row with these values, but it **will not** carry over values from the deleted row into the new one. In other words, you need **all** the combined values in the `ContentValues` if you expect a replace to occur. It's not like an `UPDATE` where you can set the values of just certain columns.

You should probably try to do an actual [`update`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) instead. Make sure to use a proper `WHERE` clause so you only update rows that matter.

I may be misunderstanding your approach, but the description makes it seem like you are inserting two rows, then trying to update and/or combine them both later. This doesn't make sense to me, and I foresee bugs whereby you have leftover rows that are incomplete and need to be cleaned up. In my opinion, it's better to structure the code so there is one `INSERT`, and every operation thereafter is an `UPDATE` on the row of interest.

Comment: Thank you so so much for recommending I try update, after some tinkering it worked perfectly